# What's the default ordering of the filesystems listed by `df`?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

What's the default ordering of the filesystems listed by `df`?

I don't see the information mentioned in http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/df1.html.

My output is

```
dernoncout@ilcompn0:~$ df
Filesystem                      1K-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
udev                             98966056           0    98966056   0% /dev
tmpfs                            19798420       43932    19754488   1% /run
/dev/sda1                       476737544   426149340    26348232  95% /
tmpfs                            98992088        2760    98989328   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5120           4        5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            98992088           0    98992088   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                      3789822616  2327874144  1269429920  65% /mnt/ilcompn0d1
cgmfs                                 100           0         100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
10.122.72.119:/mnt/ilcompf9d1 77823808512 71710353408  2206690304  98% /mnt/ilcompf9d1
tmpfs                            19798420          28    19798392   1% /run/user/109
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/1015
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/1014
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/10201
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/1012
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/10508
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/1025
ilcompf0:/mnt/ilcompf0d0      70041414656 54306734080 12218591232  82% /mnt/ilcompf0d0
tmpfs                            19798420           0    19798420   0% /run/user/10219
```

so I don't see any clear ordering.

Comment: POSIX states _"The format of the default output from df is unspecified"_ - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html#tag_20_33

Comment: Your question is good, I think it's related to kernel needed, If you see `udev` is first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df`’s output format [is unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html), including the order of the file systems.

Under Linux, GNU `df` now bases its output on the contents of `/proc/self/mountinfo`; entries there are listed in the order in which they were added to the current [mount namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html).